# How to send control codes to Epson dot matrix printer from Windows

Tags: c#, escaping, sequence, epson

I want to send some control codes to EPSON printer. I've tried on many ways, send raw text file from command prompt, making program for print on c#, create generic/text only printer, but nothing work. When I am sending code, printer do nothing, the printer is using ESC/P2 control sets.

Comment: i'm not voting you to close but do read this [Send ESC commands to a printer in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837786/send-esc-commands-to-a-printer-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

Answer (score 0):

Here u can get Epson Printer codes

http://www.lprng.com/DISTRIB/RESOURCES/PPD/epson.htm

U need to append those chars in your printing text when sending your text to print.

Comment: I know these codes, but I don't know how to send, I want to use ESC EM 66 control code for ejecting, but this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you append the ESC character also printed on the Page. How to  NOT  to print command on page.

vivek