# C# printing images on continuous roll cutting off at the end of the page

Tags: c#, .net, printing, .net-4.5

I'm currently thinking about a problem I've run across.

I have a printer with "infinite" roll of paper and list of images to print.

The printer can cut the paper after the page has been printed and i need to write an application that will print a page and then cut it off after the page has been printed. (preferably in one print job not many print jobs for every page printed).

**I've googled and found the command to send to the printer to cut the page.**

I'm thinking of using `.NET 4.5` and `PrintDocument` class, but I'm a newb in printing and don't have a clear idea about how to achieve that. Can I please get an advice or an example of how to achieve that and if it is possible?

Question:

**Is there an example of how to compose the printDocument && include the page cut command after every page is printed?**

Comment: This may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837786/send-esc-commands-to-a-printer-in-c-sharp

Comment: I've read that one :) It seemed a bit too complicated for me, but i might give it a try if nothing better appears...

Answer (score -1):

i was suffer this problem , to achieve this you must use printer API, those provided you client if you do not have SDK then it is not possible to implement ok.